# Static analysis for a specification document (boston housing authority)

Tags: testing, static, analysis

I want to do a static analysis for a bunch of specification documents. the specification documents are the Boston Housing Authority - "intake and screening", "leased housing" , and "Inspections" (http://www.bostonhousing.org/detpages/deptinfo128.html). I know I am suppose to inspect the documents; but the requirements look perfectly stated and specified, so I don't know what else I should do. Please how should I go about it?